# SwiftUI Equivalent for UIKIt's AutoEnable Return Key?

Tags: swiftui, keyboard, return, key, disable

Is there a SwiftUI equivalent of the UIKit setting "Auto-Enable Return Key", which disables the return key in the keyboard if nothing is in the field, but automatically enables it if there is text? Can't seem to locate this option. I simply want to disable the screen keyboard's Return key value if nothing is in a TextField, but otherwise have it enabled. Thx!